# Inserting kmstr when function argument is missing

Tags: conditional-statements, emacs, arguments

I need to modify this function in a way that `kmstr` is inserted when `systr` is missing as an argument.

```
(defun imprint (imprint kmstr systr)

  (if (equal imprint "Command")
      (insert kmstr)
    (insert systr)))
```

Comment: Where did you get this function from? What are you trying to do with it? As posted, this is a generic programming question, and as such is a better fit on stackoverflow. What context makes it emacs-specific?

Comment: My grandmother gave it to me for Christmas.  Same old story about the aggressive moderator who is constantly unwilling to let others work in peace.  Besides, not being so good on the topics being moderated.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defun imprint (imprint kmstr systr)
  (if (and (not systr)  (equal imprint "Command"))
      (insert kmstr)
    (insert systr)))
```

Comment: If I use `(or (not systr) (equal imprint "Command"))` this would mean that if `systr` does not exist, `kmstr` would be inserted whether `"Command"` in used or not.  Yes?  There are instances where `systr` is not available, and have to insert `kmstr` instead.